# Unable to Initialize TDSE object Failed to decrypt using provider 'TridionRsaProtectedConfigurationProvider'

Tags: 2011, 2011-sp1

I am trying to upgrade from SDL Tridion 2011 to SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 but after upgrading the database, I am getting the following error:

> Unable to Initialize TDSE object. Failed to decrypt using provider 'TridionRsaProtectedConfigurationProvider'. Error message from the provider: Bad Data.

What should I do? I have already restarted COM+, IIS and the entire machine.

Also a lock icon is showing for `Tridion.ContentManager.config`

Comment: Did you also upgrade the software? Or just the database?

Comment: As of now i have just updated the DB but i have notice while upgrading the DB is not allowing me to upgrade "Audience Manager" DB. so the upgrade is in mid

Comment: OK. The software will not work for sure until it's upgraded too - you need to do both in sync. Regarding your Audience Manager upgrade, that seems more serious. Probably worth involving Customer Support.

Comment: For the `Unable to Initialize TDSE object. Failed to decrypt using provider 'TridionRsaProtectedConfigurationProvider'. Error message from the provider: Bad Data` error, did you rename the machine, or copy the `Tridion.ContentManager.config` file from another server?

Comment: Can you also ensure the `Tridion.ContentManager.config` is valid XML?

Comment: Hi I think the issue exists as i have modified the file with local user and not with the admin user, it has been resolved i have just reverted the config file with old one and restarted the server now its appearing fine but now the new problem occur , now in CMS the "Audience Manager" tab is not showing and also in admin tab its not showing me the Audience and Synchronization target any idea what went wrong?

Comment: user36299 submitted this new issue here: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/13530/audience-manager-and-synchronization-target-not-showing-in-administration-ta

Comment: maybe you try to upgrade with a different administrator user of original installation. Can you access to Tridion Content Manager Console? I think your user aren't granted to decrypt RSAKey. The lock icon indicates the permission inheritance is lost.