# "Audience Manager" and "Synchronization Target" not showing in Administration Tab- SDL Tridion 2011

Tags: 2011, 2011-sp1, outbound-email, audience-manager, schema-synchronization

I have just clone my local environment where i cloned my CMS/CDS/DB , also got the license from tridion for these new environment.I have updated value in all configuration files and updated the licence files but for the new clone server i am not able to see the "Audience Manager" and "Synchronization Target" in Administration Tab. For the original environments this is not the case.

Can you please help, just have a doubt is it because the licence provided for these clone server is not allowing the "Audience Manager"?

Comment: The CM logs should show any license issues. Do you see the license recognized for the new server and can you check the allowed modules match between licenses?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually it was a slightly silly one :(

The licence file for the cloned server was missing a licence for Audience Manager.

Steps to investigate:

1. Tried starting all Tridion Outbound E-mail services and got an issue while starting  "Tridion Outbound E-mail Synchronization"
2. Went to Event Viewer and had a look in the Tridion error event log
3. Saw the error saying the "licence for Audience manager is not valid"

Answer (score 5):

I can only think of two reasons why they would not show up in the Administration tab:

1. You do not have a valid Audience Manager license.
2. Audience Manager was not installed.

Listed in order of likelihood :)